# Make input with' hidden=true' value show by changing state in React.JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a React.js application. I cannot find the way to change the hidden input to show so I decided to post a question here.

The functionality I want to implement :

If you click a text, a checkbox should be appeared. This checkbox is `input` and there is `hidden=true`inside the tag.

As long as I know, we can use ternary operator to change the styling inside JSX tag. However ternary operator does not work for hidden element.

Here is [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/qPxZoB).

The code

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    hidden: true
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        hidden: !this.state.hidden
    })
}

render() {
return(
       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" 
           id="boldCheckbox"
           hidden={{ !this.state.hidden ?  'false' : 'true' }}  
           />
        <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.handleClick}  >
       {this.props.text}              
       </span>
       </div>
      );
   }
 }

 React.render(
 <div>
 <FontChooser min='4' max='40'  text='Fun with React!' bold='false'/>
 </div>,
 document.getElementById('container'));
```

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Did you try using just `false` and `true` values instead of string values? Strings are truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pair of extra {}

If you do this it should work:

`hidden={ !this.state.hidden ?  true : false }`

Comment: ohh..! I just added same brackets as inline style. It worked! I will mark it once 6 mins pass.  Thank you!!

Comment: hidden = { !this.state.hidden ?  true : false } is equal to hidden = { !this.state.hidden }.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
hidden={{ !this.state.hidden ?  'false' : 'true' }}
```

You should have

```
type={!this.state.hidden ?  'hidden' : 'checkbox'}
```

Comment: why not use hidden? like nick answer, with type you need to know the type of input for every input

Comment: @stackdave a bit late here, but the `hidden` element attribute completely hides the element from the view, making it effectively non-existent. An `input` with `type="hidden"` would still be part of a form, and its value will be sent.
It would depend on what's needed.